# How to process the results of a series of AJAX requests sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I need to populate an HTML table using records retrieved via a series of AJAX
requests.  The AJAX requests are all generated in a while loop.  The total number of requests made is governed by a value provided by the server in a previous exchange of information.  The AJAX requests need to be handled asynchronously while the results of the request need to be processed in the order in which originally requested.

The problem, of course is that the responses to the requests do not always 
get answered in order.   So, after reading up on jquery's Deferred/promise interface I thought I had a solution in hand.  But for the life of me can't get my head around how to defer the processing (populating the table) of the results of a requests until the results of previous request(s) have been hanlded.  I've found many examples on StackOverflow that get me close, but I can't seem to connect the dots to get it all working in my application.

First I tried using an array of Deferred objects, thinking that I could use indexed references to them to make the processing of one set of records dependent upon the completion of the processing of the previous set (in "as requested" order) set of data.  But I couldn't figure out how to create a promise/Deferred object associated with the actual processing of the data - using .then().

```
var deferreds = [];
var recsPerPkt = 20;
var recRqstd = 0;

while(recsRqstd < totalRecsAvailable) {

    console.log("Next record index to request: " + nextNdxRqst)

    // Collect an array of the "promise" objects that $.ajax() returns for each call.
    deferreds.push( $.ajax({
            url: 'eventSummaryData',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            data: {StartNdxNum: nextNdxRqst, NumRecords: recsPerPkt}
        })   // End $.ajax({ url: 'trainSummaryData', ...
    ); // End deferreds.push()

    recsRqstd += recsPerPkt;
    nextNdxRqst = recsRqstd;

    if (deferreds.length > 1)    
    {
        deferreds[deferreds.length - 2].then(        
            function (jsonData) {

                if (jsonData.ok) {

                    // Now display the rows/records included in this packet.
                    displayrRecordsInTable({"rows": jsonData.rows});    
                }
            },
            function(){
                $('#error-msg').text('HTTP error: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        ); 
    } 
} 

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).then( function(){
    console.log("Processing of AJAX'd data complete. ")

    configureTableControls();
});
```

Then I found a "pattern" that chained the processing functionality using then(),
but the example didn't quite fit my exact situation and ended up having no reference to the http response data in my process-the-data handler.  When I run this, the browser logs to the console,  "jsonData undefined" .

```
var prevPromise = $.Deferred().resolve();
var recsPerPkt = 20;
var recRqstd = 0;

while(recsRqstd < totalRecsAvailable) {
    prevPromise = prevPromise.then(function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'eventSummaryData',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            data: {StartNdxNum: nextNdxRqst, NumRecords: recsPerPkt}
        }); 
    }).then(function (jsonData) {

            if (jsonData.ok) {
                // Now display the rows/records included in this packet.
                displayTrainSummaryRows({"rows": jsonData.rows});
            }
        },
        function(){
            $('#error-msg').text('HTTP error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    );

    recsRqstd += recsPerPkt;
    nextNdxRqst = recsRqstd;
}
```

So, how can I enforce the processing of AJAX requested data in the sequence in
which the requests were originally made?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't fire off a request until the previous one has succeeded. Look to consolidate requests -- Why return a response that will only be sent back to the server unaltered for the next response? Process sets in bulk rather than through iteration, etc.

Comment: Sorry, intent was to increment nxtNdxRqst on each iteration.  I edited my question to reflect this.  Lost this when tailoring my original code to post here.

Comment: Then maintain a keyed dictionary in your client-side code and have your AJAX responses return the same key.

Comment: Please don't minify your own variable names; the minifier will do that for you. /rant

Comment: I need the requests to be "issued" asynchronously, and the results to be posted to the table as soon as possible, in order to keep the UI from appearing to be hung.  Application consists of an embedded http server running on a 3x5 sized processor board, tethered to a cellular modem - response times are completely unpredictable and erratic.

Comment: Do you want the results to be processed in sequence but the requests sent in parallel? Shouldn't be too much of a problem

Comment: Yes. Sorry I wasn't more clear about that.  Ideally, we need for the requests to be sent in parallel, and the results of those requests to be processed in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using native [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) over jQuery's deferred objects. They are much more readable, easier to understand, native to the language, and have increasing browser support (with the exception of all IE versions). To account for browser support, use a polyfill like [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) and you'll be set. [This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) does a good job of explaining the basics of promises.

### Print results one by one, slower overall

Check out the section of that article I linked to, titled "Parallelism and sequencing" because that really goes in depth on how this works. Essentially you need to create a promise generator function, some sort of mapping for how many ajax requests you need to make (in this case just an array that goes up by 20 each time), and a `sequence` variable that holds the previous promise that was looped through.

```
var totalRecsAvailable = 10; //generated elsewhere apparently
var recsPerPkt = 20;
var nextNdxRqst = 0;
var recordRanges = [];
var sequence = Promise.resolve(); //initialize to empty resolved promise

//this generates a promise
function getMyData(startPosition) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'eventSummaryData',
            data: {StartNdxNum: startPosition, NumRecords: recsPerPkt}
            success: function(response){resolve(response);},
            error: function(response){reject(response);}
        });
    });
}

//build out array to inform our promises what records to pull & in which order
for (var i = 0; i < totalRecsAvailable; i++) {
    recordRanges.push(nextNdxRqst);
    nextNdxRqst += recsPerPkt;
}

//loop through record ranges, chain promises for each one
recordRanges.forEach(function(range) {
    sequence = sequence.then(function() {
        return getMyData(range); // return a new Promise
    }).then(function(data) {
        //do stuff with the data
        addToHtmlTable(data.something);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        //something went wrong
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

As outlined in that article, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of a `forEach` is actually a bit better, but I thought this was more clear what was happening.

### Wait until all processes resolve, faster overall

For slightly faster performance, you should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This takes an iterable (like an array) of promises, runs those promises asynchronously, and then saves the results to an array *in the order they were passed*. If one of the promises fails, the whole thing will fail and give an error. This sounds exactly like what you need. For example, you could do something like this:

```
var recsPerPkt = 20;
var nextNdxRqst = 0;
var totalRecsAvailable = 10; //generated elsewhere apparently
var promises = [];

//this generates a promise
function getMyData(startPosition, recordsNumber) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'eventSummaryData',
            data: {StartNdxNum: startPosition, NumRecords: recordsNumber}
            success: function(response){resolve(response);},
            error: function(response){reject(response);}
        });
    });
}

//create list of promises
for (var i = 0; i < totalRecsAvailable; i++) {
    promises.push(getMyData(nextNdxRqst,recsPerPkt));
    nextNdxRqst += recsPerPkt;
}

//This will run once all async operations have successfully finished
Promise.all(promises).then(
    function(data){
        //everything successful, handle data here
        //data is array of results IN ORDER they were passed
        buildTable(data);
    },
    function(data){
        //something failed, handle error here
        logoutError(data);
    }
);
```

That should set you down the right path.

Comment: Since there is poor browser support, at this time really requires a polyfill as you mentioned, but your solution is highly useful.

Comment: That is a great approach - thanks for taking the time to outline it for me.  However, we're really trying to avoid having to wait upon receipt of **all** the data/records before starting to display them - if at all possible.

Comment: @fjcraft you have two options. either send the requests one at a time, which will start displaying results very quickly, but take longer overall, or send them all at once and don't display any until they're all done. pick one.

Comment: @Kevin B it sounds like he wants the former, I'll adjust my answer to show how that can be done via native promises.

Comment: I guess another option would be a mixture of the two: batched processing. Send 5 requests, wait till they're complete, display, send next 5, etc till done

Comment: OP doesn't have to pick. see my answer

Comment: Okay, my answer is edited to show using native promises to print the sections as they are loaded, but still in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you to both Andy Noelker and thedarklord47 for such complete and appropriate answers.  The referenced article was a tremendous help.  Mr. Noelker's answer seems the most comprehensive for my use case, so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any jQuery function that does what you want, but here is a function `processInOrder` that will not perform your callback until all previous async ops have resolved while still allowing you to access their results

```
function processInOrder(arr, cb){
    if( arr.length > 0 ){
        arr[0].then(function(result){
            cb(result);
            processInOrder(arr.slice(1), cb);
        });
    }
}

var deferreds = [];
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    deferreds.push( asyncRequest(i) );
}

processInOrder(deferreds, display);
```

Note that while I'm not positive, I'm fairly sure that this form of recursion does not nuke the call stack for large numbers of requests.

Here it is in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1jrv952/1/)

Comment: *"I'm fairly sure that this form of recursion does not nuke the call stack for large numbers of requests"* i'm pretty sure it won't either. I think this will work most of the time, however, in the rare event that the first one finishes last it would be no different than mine. but generally it should work better than mine.

Comment: true, worst case it is no different than your answer